# How do i forward the HTTP request back to the browser? Proxy Java

Tags: java, http, proxy, request

```
final int portNumber = 8128;
String str;

int start = 0;
int endSg = 0;
int endCom = 0;

String ReqWeb=null;

System.out.println("Creating server socket on port " + portNumber);
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

BufferedReader inFromServer;
OutputStream out;
PrintWriter outw;   
Socket forwardSocket = null;

while (true)
{
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();              //get client request
    String from = socket.getInetAddress().toString();
    System.out.println("Accepted connection from " + from);
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
    pw.println("What's your request?");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    //System.out.println(str);
    while((str = br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(str);     
        if(str!=null){
            start = str.indexOf("Host: ") + 6;
            endSg = str.indexOf(".sg", start) + 3;
            endCom = str.indexOf(".com", start) + 4;
            if(((endSg>3)||(endCom>4))&&(start>4)){
                if(endSg>3)
                    ReqWeb = str.substring(start, endSg);
                else if(endCom>3)
                    ReqWeb = str.substring(start, endCom);              
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(ReqWeb);

    if(ReqWeb!=null){
        //ReqWeb = str.substring(start);
        System.out.println(ReqWeb);
        forwardSocket = new Socket(ReqWeb, 80);
    }

    pw.println(str);
    pw.println(ReqWeb);     
    //socket.close();

    if(forwardSocket!=null){
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(forwardSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = forwardSocket.getOutputStream();
        outw = new PrintWriter(out, false);
        outw.print(str);
    }

}
```

#### Output :

```
Creating server socket on port 8128
Accepted connection from /127.0.0.1
null
Accepted connection from /127.0.0.1
GET (http://)stackoverflow.com/questions/12900825/how-do-i-forward-the-http-request-back-to-the-browser-proxy-java HTTP/1.0
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
```

now this is the output i got, should i store in a byte array to send it back to the server to request for the page? I am still having trouble forwarding this request ):

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open another socket to the intended target (as per firefox's request) and send the request there. Keep the socket that's connected to firefox open because when you get the response from the intended target, you'll read it from the target and write it back to firefox. Depending on your pipelining settings in firefox, the connection either may then close or may make more requests.

Comment: I have updated my code, now the output is What's your request? GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.0 www.google.com , i tried opening a socket with the host. now how do i actually forward the request? i tried sending the str straight but it seems like it doesnt work

Comment: You have a long way to go. For one, you're not reading everything from the firefox request. You're using `br.readLine()` which is only the first line, there's probably about 4 or 5 more lines of headers at least. One of those lines is a "Host" header, that's who you need to connect to and you need to send it the entire request (including headers you aren't receiving).

Comment: Ok i have tried to retrieve the header stuffs, and these are what i got.